# Notation for square of a probability

Tags: probability, notation

Not sure if this is the right place to be asking, but I wanted to clarify what is the more standard notation to be using for the square of a probability - $p(x)^2$ or $p^2(x)$?

Comment: I would write $$(p(x))^2$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Thank you. Surely this is better than the 2 alternatives in the question. I only worry about the case where space is a constraint. Is there any other option in this case that you might be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to add extra brackets, use $p(x)^2$. $(p(x))^2$ is probably better, although may clutter expressions with brackets. Writing the power before the argument is only used for certain named functions, primarily the trigonometrical and hyperbolic ones, and occasionally things like the logarithm: otherwise, it is usually interpreted as functional composition.

Comment: Thank you. That clears things up.